# Randomizing Post Links Outside of Loop - No Author or Date

Tags: post-meta, author, date-time, date

I'm developing a home page that is a mishmash of a bunch of information, including a random smattering of several categories, including blog posts (category 192 in the code below)

I'm obviously not invoking the standard WP loop to do this. Is there a way to get the date and author to echo properly:

```
<!-- RANDOM BLOG POST INSERTION -->
<?php $rand_posts = get_posts('cat=192&numberposts=2&orderby=rand'); foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<div class="box tall blogBox">
    <h2>Blog <span>| <?php the_date('m/d/Y'); ?></span></h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('01HomeThumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="113" height="111" /></a>
    <h3>by <?php the_author(); ?></h3>
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="readPost">Read Post</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The two issues I'm experiencing I think are both because I'm outside of the loop, but unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get the info I need.

Basically, I am randomize 2 blog posts. Everything outputs as expected, except the date and the author. I know `<?php the_author(); ?>` is deprecated, but it's not returning the expected author anyway. The other thing not working is `the_date`. It seems to output on the first outputted blog post, but subsequent are blank.

Any help would be appreciated on either of these.

I'm building this on a custom theme based on the twenty ten theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is covered on the [`get_posts` codex page: Access all post data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data) using the [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) function:

```
foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
```

Regarding [`the_date`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date), see the note about multiple instances on a page:

> SPECIAL NOTE: When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag the_time() or get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.